# Valences of atoms in covalent compound

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

1 does the valency of an atom in a covalent bond  equals the number of bonds it has with  the other atoms in that compound?

2 If "yes" then typically to bonds  chlorine has in NaCl04
It has a valency of 7 ?? I know it has an oxidation number of 7+ at that case. 
And what I know too that oxidation number / state = valency

Comment: the things you are mixing are oxidation state and valency.there is a lot of  difference between them.

Comment: Yes I know that valency and oxidation state have diffrent defintions but the same numeric value.Am I right?

Comment: No you are wrong.In carbon monoxide the oxidation state is +2 while valency of carbon is 4.

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. The oxidation state of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valency is defined as the maximum number of univalent (e.g. hydrogen) atoms that an atom can bond to. In NaClO4, Cl is indeed has 7 bonds, but this is beyond the scope of the definition of valency and is referred to as "hypervalency" or "octet expansion" and basically means that the atom in question has more than 8 electrons in its valence shell.

The idea that oxidation state = valency does not always apply. The numbers may be the same in some cases, but not always, especially not for carbons in organic compounds. The oxidation number shows you the how electron rich/deficient is a given atom in a compound (single atoms have o.s. of 0).

Example: the C atom is tetravalent in all organic compounds. Take methane CH4 and methanol CH3OH. In both molecules the carbon is connected to 4 other atoms, however, in CH4 its o.s.= -4 and in CH3OH it's -2. Another example would be formaldehyde HCHO, where the carbon has an oxidation state of 0.